# Rule based styling in OpenLayers 4

Tags: openlayers

I uploaded some shapefiles to GeoServer and I added them to OpenLayers map using WFS protocol. Now I want to style them by some properties. How can I do this?

Comment: Use a style function to process each feature by its properties.  See the script  https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/resources/mapbox-streets-v6-style.js  used in this example https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html but the technique is equally valid for WFS features.

Comment: @Mike I would recommend example from the latest version of OpenLayers: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html.

Comment: @TomazicM The question specifies OpenLayers 4 so the NPM syntax in the OL5 examples could be confusing

Comment: @Mike Ups, I overlooked it in title.